# How to migrate data in CnosDB cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, migrate, cnosdb

After adding a new data node, I want to migrate some data from the old node to the new, balancing the disk storage space of each server. How should I migrate?

Data can be smoothly migrated between nodes.